# C# Command Line Script Ending Prematurely in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, crash, command-line-interface

(Sorry if a few parts aren't correct...
I'm a bit of a novice to C# syntax)

I am currently working on a command line project. The project involves creating an algorithm that solves Problem 4 on Project Euler:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=4

From the beginning, ever since I have started the challenges, I've mainly been using Visual Studio to solve them. I've been using a "C# Command Line' type project for the interpretation of information.
Ever since I started using this type of windows form, I've found that as soon as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Insert Code Here...
    }
```

Function finished its events and arguments, it suddenly crashed (well, closed)

I believe that this is because it has and end, it ends itself...

I may be wrong...

In the meantime, I simply used a Thread.Sleep() function as a temporary fix.

How can I solve this problem, and why do you think this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. When I am still developing I usually add a Console.ReadKey(); line as the last line in the Main() method to ensure a pause.

Comment: Sorry! Here's my thought process: Created Code, Checked Code for Errors,  Started Debug. As soon as it began Debugging, it went through the code and automatically closed.

Comment: I tried the Console.ReadKey(); method. It works great! Thanks!

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Your code here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This code will only run if your code fails
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());  // Show the exception on the console.
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); // Make a pause so that the screen does not dissapears when I hit Debug -> Run
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the project using `ctrl` + `F5` instead of just `F5`. This is a lot cleaner than adding an unnecessary line to detect keypress at the end of the program IMO